# How to find a compact expression for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac k{(K+1)!}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, closed-form

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac k{(K+1)!}$$

How to find a compact expression?

(Original scan [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCRY3.gif))

Comment: what is a compact expression? and is the $K$ the same as $k$ ?

Comment: The denominator is a constant, pull it out. Then you have a sum which you should recognize.

Comment: A comptact expression probably means 'closed formula'. Regarding the different sizes of K, since this is was originally posted as an image, they probably are different.

Comment: OP might not be looking for different $k$ and $K$, but for the same $k$, you have the sum as $\dfrac{n!-1}{n!}$.(Which is interesting to prove *without* induction)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\frac k{(k+1)!}=\frac{k+1-1}{(k+1)!}=\frac{k+1}{(k+1)\cdot k!}-\frac1{(k+1)!}=\frac1{k!}-\frac1{(k+1)!}$$

Can you recognize the [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?